# Using Hook (UseDispatch) outside a function (Promise)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, redux-toolkit

I have a problem for using hook outside a function.
I made a loading state by **Redux-toolkit** which have One state **loading** and a function for **toggleLoading**.

here is my service file for my request

```c
const fetchService: ({}: {
token?: string
url: string
method?: string
addContentTypeApplicationJson?: boolean
body?: any
formData?: any
options?: any
}) => Promise<{ data: any; status: number }> = async ({
token = '',
url,
method = 'GET',
body = {},
}) => {
let status: number
const headers: any = {
 'end-username': UserService.getUsername(),
 Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
}
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
dispatch(toggleLoading())
try {
 const response = await fetch(url, {
   method: method,
   headers: headers,
   body: body,
 })
 status = response.status
 const responseJson = await response.json()
 return { status: status, data: responseJson }
 dispatch(toggleLoading())
} catch (e) {
 toast.error('Network Error!')
 dispatch(toggleLoading())
 return { status: 500, data: {} }
}

}
export { fetchService }
```

now i made a loading with redux toolkit like this

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { RootState } from '../Store'

export interface ConfigState {
  loading: boolean
}

const initialState: ConfigState = {
  loading: false,
}

export const configSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'configs',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleLoading: (state) => {
      state.loading = state.loading === true ? false : true
    },
  },
})

export const { toggleLoading } = configSlice.actions

export const ConfigInfo = (state: RootState) => state.appConfigs

export default configSlice.reducer
```

Now i want to use **ToggleLoading** in **fetchService** but i got this error

[image]

Comment: Where did you use the `useAppDispatch()` hook? show the code, and check the error stack.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i updated the fetchservice code and add two lines of code if you can check `const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
dispatch(toggleLoading())` @LinDu

Comment: You can't use react hooks in a js regular function, see https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html